# Docker espeakbox: What do I do now?

Tags: docker, text-to-speech

Seems real simple, but I'm not sure what to do now. I have docker on OSX and I'm want to try out espeakbox. So I ran

the command mentioned [here](https://github.com/parente/espeakbox).

to "run a [container](https://github.com/parente/espeakbox)"

It's evidently running:

```
bash-3.2$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
705a605786c7        parente/espeakbox    "/server"                34 seconds ago      Up 33 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   espeakbox
```

So, what do I do now, to use see it, hear it, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's full instructions on the GitHub page, so I'm loath to answer this question. However, I'm assuming the confusion is that you're not sure where the container is running. If you're using boot2docker, Just do:

```
$ curl http://$(boot2docker ip):8080/speech?text=hello
```

I assume it sends back an mp3 file.

Basically, the `docker run` command told Docker to forward port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host. When using boot2docker, the host is a Virtualbox VM, so we need to use the IP of the VM to connect to the service.

Comment: Didn't see full instructions, but thanks. I think the missing piece for me was  $(boot2docker ip)